# Widgets doesn't show up while launching Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing a eclipase based plugin where i've created an application (using SWT). There are two classes viz; `RunAction.java` which consists of `run()` , `dispose()` and `init()` methods and `Sample.java` which consists of the sample application with a Label widget. Now, when i test the application by Running it as an Eclipse application, onlt the shell is displayed without the label widget. **What is the issue?** I'm sharing the code.

> RunAction.java

```
public class RunWizardAction extends Action implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
    /** Called when the action is created. */ 
    Sample samp=new Sample();
    Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();


    public void init(IWorkbenchWindow window) {

    }

    /** Called when the action is discarded. */ 
    public void dispose() {
    }

    /** Called when the action is executed. */ 
    public void run(IAction action) {


        //InvokatronWizard wizard= new InvokatronWizard();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            samp.sampleApp(shell);

                    }
        }).start();
        }
}
```

---

> Sample.java (The sample function)

```
public void sampleApp(Shell shell) {
              Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Hello");
        JLabel lab=new JLabel("Hello World");
        Label username_checkout=new Label(shell, SWT.BOLD);
        username_checkout.setText("User Name");
        Button button=new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("push");
        shell.open();
        shell.setSize(270,270);
        while (!shell1.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
          }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Shell` doesn't have a layout. This code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    /* SET LAYOUT */
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("Hello");
    JLabel lab = new JLabel("Hello World");
    Label username_checkout = new Label(shell, SWT.BOLD);
    username_checkout.setText("User Name");
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("push");
    shell.open();
    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(270, 270);
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Besides, there are too many `Shell`s in your code:

```
public void sampleApp(Shell shell) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
```

So, now you have two `Shell`s called `shell` (which btw won't compile)...

```
while (!shell1.isDisposed())
```

And there is a third one. What's up with that?

Answer (score 3):

Your sample application would be fine if you were running outside of Eclipse like Baz's answer.

Since you're running inside of Eclipse, you already have a Display and a Shell.  Use them.

```
public void sampleApp(Shell shell) { 
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("Hello");
    JLabel lab=new JLabel("Hello World");
    Label username_checkout=new Label(shell, SWT.BOLD);
    username_checkout.setText("User Name");
    Button button=new Button(shell,SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("push");
    shell.setSize(270,270);
    shell.open();
}
```